# I need help separating class code in C++ LNK2005 and LNK1169

Tags: c++

I'm new at C++ and I have to create a simple video game, that has an enemy class, the problem comes when I try to separate the enemy code from the main.cpp, creating enemy.h and enemy.cpp, I followed all instructions I saw on the internet but it keeps showing me the error message I hope you guys can help me.

**enemy.cpp file**

```
#include "enemy.h"

enemy::enemy(int _hp, int _attackValue, string _name) {
    hp = _hp;
    attackValue = _attackValue;
    name = _name;
}

void enemy::attack(enemy agressor, enemy objective) {
    objective.set_hp(objective.hp - agressor.attackValue);
    objective.showinfo(objective, 2);
}

void enemy::showinfo(enemy enemy, int hero) {
    if (hero == 1) {
        cout << "     \n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        cout << enemy.name;
        cout << "     \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        for (int i = enemy.hp / 5; i > 0; i--) {
            cout << "|";
        }
        cout << "     \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        cout << enemy.hp;
    }
    else {
        cout << "                                   \n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        cout << enemy.name;
        cout << "                                   \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        for (int i = enemy.hp / 5; i > 0; i--) {
            cout << "|";
        }
        cout << "                                   \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        cout << enemy.hp;
    }
}

int enemy::get_hp() {
    return hp;
}

void enemy::set_hp(int _hp) {
    hp = _hp;
}

int enemy::get_attackValue() {
    return attackValue;
}

string enemy::get_name() {
    return name;
}
```

**enemy.h file**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef enemy_H
#define enemy_H

class enemy {

private:

    int hp, attackValue;
    string name;
public:
    enemy();
    enemy(int, int, string);
    void attack(enemy, enemy);
    void showinfo(enemy, int);
    int get_hp();
    void set_hp(int hp);
    int get_attackValue();
    string get_name();
};

#endif // !enemy_H
```

PD: I still don't know how to implement setcursorposition in c++ as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `enemy()` but haven't defined it. If you declare the default constructor, make sure you define it (possibly in your .cpp file)

Answer (score 0):

That [error that you get](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xttf5w7w.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) means that you violated [ODR (one definition rule)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). In other words, when you tried to separate your `enemy` class from your main you didn't remote all the parts from there and ended up with the same code in multiple cpp files.

As a side note, looks like you forgot to define your enemy::enemy() constructor, or forgot to move it from main.cpp to enemy.cpp?